# git for-each-ref with <pattern> returns nothing

Tags: git, git-branch

**git branch --list '*hotfix*'** returns a list of branches that contain the word 'hotfix' inside the branch name, whereas
**git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname)' '*hotfix*'** return nothing, not even */n* symbol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git branch` is looking (by default) at just the branches - the refs in `refs/heads` - so it lets you use patterns that match just the "branch name" (e.g. `some-hotfix` which is actually shorthand for the full ref name `refs/heads/some-hotfix`).

`for-each-ref` is looking at all refs, so it doesn't let you use such patterns.  You can use something like `refs/heads/*hotfix*` if you know that you're only interested in branches (or something like `**/*hotfix*` if not).

Answer (score 4):

As [the document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt-ltpatterngt82308203) of `git for-each-ref` says,

> If one or more patterns are given, only refs are shown that match
>   against at least one pattern, either using fnmatch(3) or literally, in
>   the latter case matching completely or from the beginning up to a
>   slash.

and as [the document](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) of `fnmatch` says,

> The fnmatch() function checks whether the string argument matches the
>   pattern argument, which is a shell wildcard pattern (see glob(7)).

and as a branch is like a path `refs/heads/foo/bar`, the pattern here should be `refs/heads/**/*hotfix*`,

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname)' 'refs/heads/**/*hotfix*'
```

If you also want the remote branches,

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname)' 'refs/heads/**/*hotfix*' 'refs/remotes/**/*hotfix*'
```

The 2 patterns match branches like `hotfix`, `origin/hotfix-118`, `hotfix-118`, `118-hotfix`, `my-hotfix-110`.

Comment: Since the `glob(3)`/`glob(7)` pages explicitly say _A '/' in a pathname cannot be matched by a '?' or '*' wildcard_, and no mention of the `**` syntax (or its limitations) is made in those pages, we can perhaps give the OP the benefit of the doubt.  Mentally mapping a feature documented in Bash to one in Git isn't difficult, but it's certainly not in the man pages you mention.